# Akka system get actor selection by class

Tags: scala, akka, actor

Is it possible to send message to some actor selection only specific type of class?

Here code for getting actor selection by path:

```
Akka.system.actorSelection("/path")
```

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible, since actors are defined by their named location and the messages they handle. This is why an `ActorSelection` can only be resolved to an `ActorRef` (whether by using `Identify` or `.resolveOne`), never betraying the implementation.

The benefit of this arrangement is that any actor can be replaced with a different implementation, a router, a proxy, etc. to accommodate changing needs of handling the messages. This is also why you send and receive messages, rather than call methods, so that the receiver of a message and any eventual reply message are not even tied to the same actor.

If you wish to have a class based lookup for your actors, the best way is to set up a registry actor yourself, that is notified of actor creation and keeps that information so that you can query it.